# ColdFusion XML special/foreign character loss

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing, special-characters

I'm trying to import a list of leagues from [this](http://www.easports.com/iframe/fut/bundles/futweb/web/flash/xml/localization/messages.en_GB.xml) XML file into a table.

I'm able to find the elements I require but where the league name has a special/foreign character in it then it is not displaying it correctly.

For example, in the XML file there is the following node:

```
<trans-unit resname="global.leagueFull.2014.league1005">
    <source>Colombia Finalización</source>
</trans-unit>
```

But when I run my code the output for this league is Colombia FinalizaciÃ³n.

My code is as follows:

```
<cfscript>
    xmlContent  = xmlParse("http://www.easports.com/iframe/fut/bundles/futweb/web/flash/xml/localization/messages.en_GB.xml");
    subSet  = xmlSearch(xmlContent,'/xliff/file/body/trans-unit/');
</cfscript>

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(subset)#" index="i"> 

    <cfset resName = subSet[i].xmlAttributes.resName />

    <cfif Find("global.leagueFull.2014.league",resName)>
    
        <cfset leagueName = subSet[i].xmlChildren[1].xmlText />
        <cfset leagueID = ListLast(resName,".") />
        <cfset leagueID = Mid(leagueID,7,15) />
    
        <cfoutput>#leagueName#<br /></cfoutput>
    
    </cfif> 

</cfloop>
```

Does anyone know what might be causing the loss of these characters, and if there is a way to prevent or indeed remedy it?

Thanks

Comment: It might be the browser.  Did you look the html generated by your ColdFusion code?

Comment: Tried it in Chrome, IE & Firefox - all with the same result. Yeah viewed the source, what about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see something like `FinalizaciÃ³n` that invariably means that an UTF-8 source has been interpreted as a legacy (i.e. a one-byte-per-character) encoding.

Congratulations, you just found a bug in ColdFusion. *(As per Adam Cameron's hint in the comments, this is [Bug #3183072](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3183072) which has been fixed as of CF 11.)*

Try this work-around instead:

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.easports.com/iframe/fut/bundles/futweb/web/flash/xml/localization/messages.en_GB.xml">

<cfif ListFirst(cfhttp.statusCode, " ") eq "200">
  <cfset xmlContent = XmlParse(cfhttp.FileContent)>
  <cfset xPath = "/xliff/file/body/trans-unit[starts-with(@resname, 'global.leagueFull.2014.league')]">
  <cfset subSet = XmlSearch(xmlContent, xPath)>

  <cfloop array="#subSet#" index="transUnit">
    <cfset leagueName = transUnit.source>
    <cfset leagueID = Mid(ListLast(transUnit.XmlAttributes.resName, "."), 7, 15)>
    <cfoutput>#HTMLEditFormat(leagueName)#<br></cfoutput>
  </cfloop>
<cfelse>
  Error fetching file. (<cfoutput>#cfhttp.StatusCode#</cfoutput>)
</cfif>
```

Note that I've used XPath's `starts-with()` to replace your `<cfif>`. That's more efficient and concise.

Comment: Awesome! That's solved the issue and that starts-with is certainly a lot cleaner, great tip! Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've switched to a `<cfloop array="...">`, that's a step forward as well. See modified answer. (Also note the `HTMLEditFormat()` - as a safety precaution you ought to never output any data to HTML without first escaping it as HTML.)

Comment: @Tomalak: "Congratulations, you just found a bug in ColdFusion": it was this bug: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3183072. It's fixed in CF11.